# An Exercise in Conditional Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to prove the following statements:

Let $Z$ be a non-negative random variable on $(\Omega, F, \mathbb{P})$ and let $G$ be a sub-sigma algebra of $F.$

1. Show $\{ Z=0\} \supset \{E(Z|G)=0\}, P-a.s.$
2. Prove that for a random variable $Y$ such that $YZ$ is integrable wrt to $\mathbb{P}$ $E(YZ|G)=E(YZ|G)I_{\{E(Z|G)>0\}}$ P a.s.
3. Assume $E(Z)=1$ and define a new prob $\mathbb{Q}(A)=E(ZI_{A}), A \in F.$ Show $\mathbb{Q}(E(Z|G)>0)=1$.
4. Prove that if Y is random variable integrable wrt to $\mathbb{Q}$ then $E^{\mathbb{Q}}(Y|G)=\frac{E(YZ|G)}{E(Z|G)}, \mathbb{Q}-a.s.$

For 1. I'm not sure how you show P-a.s. inclusion.

For 2. I know that $E(E(YZ|G)I_{\{E(Z|G)>0\}})=YZE(I_{\{E(Z|G)>0\}})=YZ*P(\{E(Z|G)>0\})$.  All we know is Z is non-negative, so I don't know if you can argue that $P(\{E(Z|G)>0\})=1.$

For 3.  $\mathbb{Q}(E(Z|G)>0)=E(ZI_{\{E(Z|G)>0\}}=E(Z)*P(\{E(Z|G)>0\})=1*1=1$

Lastly, I am not sure how to attempt part 4.

Comment: "I do know that $E(\{E(Z|G)=0\})=E(\{Z=0\}$" Sorry but what does this even mean? The LHS is $E(\{E(Z|G)=0\})$, that is, $E(A)$ with $A=\{E(Z|G)=0\}$. This does not fit.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. How do I deal with expectation of these type of sets defined by conditional expectation then?

Comment: Let me repeat: E(X) is well defined when X is a random variable, E(A) with A an event does not exist. Or you use the notation in a peculiar way, which you should explain.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. So I can take the expectation of an indicator function as I attempted to in 2 because it is a r.v., but not of the set itself. So how do I show p almost sure inclusion in 1?

Comment: Any idea on your side to show 1? Note there is no context about 1 in your post except "I'm not sure".

Answer (score 1):

**1.**

Assume that $\{ Z=0\} \supset \{E(Z|G)=0\}$, P-a.s. is not true. That is, assume that there exists a set $A$ of positive probability for which $E[Z\mid G](\omega)=0$ and $Z(\omega)>0$ if $\omega\in A=\{\omega:E[Z\mid G]=0\}\cap\{\omega:Z>0\}$.

[image]

By the definition of the conditional expectation, given that $\{\omega:E[Z\mid G]=0\}$ is $G$ measurable, we have
$$0=\int_{\{\omega:E[Z\mid G]=0\}}E[Z\mid G]\ dP=\int_{\{\omega:E[Z\mid G]=0\}}Z\ dP\ge\int_AZ\ dP>0$$
which contradicts the indirect assumption.

**2.**

Now, we know that $Z=0$ if $E[Z\mid G]=0$ (a.s.).  What about $ZY$ then? $ZY$ is also $0$ assuming that $E[Z\mid G]=0$. (If $ZY$ was not integrable then we would dare to say that $ZY=0$ if $Z=0$.) So, $E[YZ\mid G]=0$ if $E[Y\mid G]=0$ except for a set of zero probability.

**3.**

For the same reason

$$Q(\{E[Z\mid G]>0\})=1-Q(\{E[Z\mid G]=0\})=1-\int_{\{E[Z\mid G]=0\}}Z\ dP=1.$$

**4.**

We have to prove that for any $G$ measurable $C$ 
$$\int_C \frac{E[YZ\mid G]}{E[Z\mid G]}\ dQ=\int_C Y \ dQ.$$

By the definition of $Q$ and because $E[Z\mid G]>0$ a.s. $Q$

$$\int_C Y\ dQ=\int_CYZ\ dP=\int_CE[YZ\mid G] \ dP=$$
$$=\int_C \frac{E[YZ\mid G]}{E[Z\mid G]}\ dQ.$$

Because $\int_RE[Z\mid G]\ dP=\int_RZ\ dP=Q(R)$ for every $G$ measurable $R$, $\frac1{E[Z\mid G]}$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $P$ with respect to $Q$.

Comment: In 1., why $E(Z\mathbf 1_A)=E(E(Z\mid G)\mathbf 1_A)$?

Comment: @Did: $E(Z1_A)=\int_AZ\ dP=\int_AE[Z\mid G]\ dP=E[E[Z\mid G]1_A].$ By the definition of $E[\cdot 1_A]$ and by the definition of the conditional expectation.

Comment: "by the definition of the conditional expectation" No. This would hold for every A in G but there is no reason to assume the event A you defined, is in G, is there?

Comment: @Did: No, there isn't. I meant $A'=\{E[Z\mid G]=0\}$ which is $G$ measurable. So, I will have to modify my answer.

Comment: @Did: I've edited the answer.

Comment: Sorry but now we have two different definitions for the same set A... Such arguments cannot work.

Comment: @zoli I have a question on your reasoning for part two.  Can you explain why "$E[YZ∣G]=0$ if $E[Y∣G]=0$ except for a set of zero probability" implies that $E(YZ|G)=E(YZ|G)I_{\{E(Z|G)>0\}}$  P a.s.

Comment: @user75514: (Please take a look at $1.$ again -- I had to correct.) So, by 1., if $E[Z\mid G]=0$ then $Z=0$. If $Z=0$ then $YZ=0 $ if $Y$ is finite. If $YZ=0$ then $E[YZ\mid G]=0$. That is, $E[YZ\mid G]=0$ if $E[Z\mid G]=0$. Another way to put this is, $E[YZ\mid G]=E[YZ\mid G]1_{\{E[Z\mid G]>0\}}$.